# How to remove X-Powered-By from header?

Tags: servlets, weblogic, response-headers

I'm using weblogic and with the response I got this header parameter:

```
X-Powered-By    Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2
```

After a simple search I realized that I have to use the following code in my `web.xml`

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.faces.sendPoweredByHeader</param-name>
   <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But ain't working for me. need to mention that this header does not appear when I deploy my application into Tomcat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In WebLogic Administration Console, click on the domainName -> Configuration tab -> Web Application sub tab.  Set "X-Powered-By Header" to "X-Powered-By Header will not be sent".

As per you below method is not working for you
To stop the X-Powered-By JSF http header related to a custom application, the following context parameter can be added to the applications web.xml:

```
 <context-param>
 <param-name>com.sun.faces.sendPoweredByHeader</param-name>
 <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

As per "Can X-Powered-By Setting Be Done in weblogic.xml or web.xml? (Doc ID 1505570.1)"
1) XPoweredBy is set at domain's WebAppContainerMBean

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/apirefs.1111/e13945/weblogic/management/configuration/WebAppContainerMBean.html#setXPoweredByHeaderLevel(java.lang.String)

setXPoweredByHeaderLevel

void setXPoweredByHeaderLevel(String xPoweredByHeaderLevel)
Sets the level for XPoweredBy header information

Parameters:
xPoweredByHeaderLevel -
See Also:
WebAppContainerMBean.getXPoweredByHeaderLevel()
Valid Values:
"NONE","SHORT","MEDIUM","FULL"

2) There is no equivalent setting in weblogic.xml and web.xml

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13712/weblogic_xml.htm
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13712/web_xml.htm

In short, this is a domain level setting, thus cannot be set at application level through weblogic.xml or web.xml.

Comment: Thanks, that totally worked.